# Hide Fields Based on Role

Tags: entities, users, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to assign permission to fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31808/is-it-possible-to-assign-permission-to-fields)

I have a contact type called contact form, and I want to alter the fields that are visible when adding that contact type, based on the user role. I want admin to be able to change the value of fields such as 'status', 'date completed' etc but I don't want these to be visible to the anonymous role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the function of [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.